# How to get suggested cardaction content on client using c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, botframework

I am using Microsoft BotFramework, and when the bot returns the suggested CardAction the content is not showing in client.

**BotCode**

```
private static async Task SendSuggestionOptionAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply("Please choose anyone of this!");
    reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
    reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
    reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
    {
        Actions = new List<CardAction>()
        {
            new CardAction() { Title = "Fourm", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Fourm" },
            new CardAction() { Title = "KB", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "KB" },
        },
    };
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
}
```

**Client Code**

```
var messagesReceived = await _httpClient.GetAsync(conversationUrl);
var messagesReceivedData = await messagesReceived.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var messagesRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BotMessageRoot>(messagesReceivedData);
```

It only shows "Please choose anyone of this!" on messgesReceivedData, but not showing the suggested CardAction content. Can someone please help identify where I made a mistake? I want to bind that suggested CardAction content to my client.

**Bot output**

```
{
   "id": "QYhDOe6oulCoU55XIoXc5|0000003",
   "conversationId": "QYhDOe6oulCoU55XIoXc5",
   "created": "2019-01-28T04:56:37.1646158Z",
   "from": "sync-test-bot",
   "text": "Please choose anyone of this!",
   "images": [],
   "attachments": []
}
```

There is no Forum and KB is showing here.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You are not receiving in the mobile? Is the problem doing the deserialization? What message are you receiving?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro,  '{
      "id": "QYhDOe6oulCoU55XIoXc5|0000003",
      "conversationId": "QYhDOe6oulCoU55XIoXc5",
      "created": "2019-01-28T04:56:37.1646158Z",
      "from": "test-bot",
      "text": "Please choose anyone of this!",
      "images": [],
      "attachments": []
    }' . I received like this. But suggestion card action content is not received.

Comment: Please anyone suggest me on this. Its really hard to find and I spend more time on researching this.

Comment: To be clear, are you building your own client using DirectLine?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Yes

Comment: Try testing your bot in the emulator so you can see the messages the bot is sending to Direct Line and see if they include suggested actions or not

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Yes I am still working on this. I have got the suggestion action on single text property. Like this("Please choose anyone on this, /n/n*Forum\n\n*KB").

Comment: Are you saying that when you apply suggested actions to your activity, the suggested actions get applied to the `text` property and the activity still contains no `suggestedActions` property? This is different from the problem you posted in your question where the text property didn't contain the suggested action text. If you're experiencing new behavior now, what changed?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the answer for sure but did you check the response header? In Outlook actionable messages, the card content is in the http header as a JavaScript object.

Comment: Charlie C is saying that your client should check the header of the incoming message. You're currently only checking the content and not the header.